# Multiplying inequalities issues

Tags: functions, inequality

It might be a very simple question for the site standard, but can anyone tell me what's the issue here?

So if I have the following function:

$f(x) = \frac{x}{ln(x)} $ for  $e \le x \le e^2$

And i want to form an inequality from it, something like: $ value1 \le f(x) \le value2$ (it might sound silly, but english is not my first language and i have a hard time describing, sorry)

So i opted for two methods, the first one being:
$f(e) \le f(x) \le f(e^2)$ (since the function is increasing for the given values of x) and we get:
$e \le \frac{x}{ln(x)} \le \frac{e^2}{2}$

But I also wanted to see if this approach worked too:

We know that:
$e \le x \le e^2$  and $ \frac{1}{2} \le \frac{1}{ln(x)} \le 1$

If we multiply these two:

$ \frac{e}{2} \le \frac{x}{ln(x)} \le e^2$

So, everything leads to two different answers.I am 100% sure the first one is correct, but what's the problem in the second case?As far as i know we are allowed to multiply the inequalities since they are both positive.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Why do you think there is something wrong with second case? If the first case is true then so is the second case since you are taking a 'bigger' range in the second inequality.

Comment: The exercise told me the inequality should look like the first one.But, i didn't put it in the light you said and it does really make sense now (it sounds extremely dumb now, i'm really sorry)

Comment: Glad it helped! (and no need to apologise!)

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, the second inequality puts looser bounds on $x/\ln x$, so if the first inequality is true, the second will be automatically true as well. Hence there is no contradiction between the two answers.

On the other hand, you might still wonder why the second method is less "precise" than the first. This is because in the inequalities $e \leq x \leq e^2$ and $\frac{1}{2}\leq \frac{1}{\ln x} \leq 1$, the lower (and upper) bounds are not achieved at the same value of $x$. In other words, when $x = e$, you reach the minimum value of $x$, but obtain the maximum value of $1$ for $\frac{1}{\ln x}$. This means that you can't actually reach the minimum $e/2$ that the second method provides.